# Как в aiogram ловить и отправлять фото одним сообщением?

Tags: python, aiogram

Нужно, что бы бот ловил несколько фото, отправленных одним сообщением, и так же одним сообщением пересылал их в канал.Пробовал сделать так:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def get_foto(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        if type(data.get('photo')) is list:
            data['photo'].append(message.photo[-1].file_id)
            data["time"] = time()
            return
        else:
            data['photo'] = [message.photo[-1].file_id]
            data["time"] = time()
    wait_time = 3
    while time() - data["time"] < wait_time:
        await sleep(0.1)
    print(data['photo'])
    #poli = data['photo'][0]
    poli = types.MediaGroup()
    poli.attach_photo(data['photo'][0])
    #print(poli['media'][0])
    await bot.send_media_group( chat_id = config.chat_id, media = poli)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        del data["time"]
        del data["photo"]
```

но не сработало. ловит и отправляет только первую фотку

Comment: наверно из-за этого `poli.attach_photo(data['photo'][0])` почему только 0 элемент?

Comment: если убрать [0] будет ошибка "aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Field "media" must be of type string". да и не в этом дело. я смотрел data['photo'] через print. там изначально только одна картинка сохраняется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, у меня работает

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def get_foto(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        if type(data.get('photo')) is list:
            data['photo'].append(message.photo[-1].file_id)
            data["time"] = time()
            return
        else:
            data['photo'] = [message.photo[-1].file_id]
            data["time"] = time()
    wait_time = 3
    while time() - data["time"] < wait_time:
        await sleep(0.5)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        poli = types.MediaGroup()
        for i in data['photo']:
            poli.attach_photo(photo=i)
        del data["time"]
        del data["photo"]

    await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=message.chat.id, media=poli)
```

Comment: спасибо! работает